# How to replace inplace with apply() function?

Tags: pandas

I have a panda dataframe df with  column DIFF_HOURS:

I do this code:

```
for i in range(0, 72, 6):
  df.loc[(df['DIFF_HOURS'] > i) & (df['DIFF_HOURS'] <= (i+6))]['DIFF_HOURS'].apply(lambda x: i)
```

But how to modify df rows inplace please with respect indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding assignment

```
  df.loc[(df['DIFF_HOURS'] > i) & (df['DIFF_HOURS'] <= (i+6)), 'DIFF_HOURS'] = df.loc[(df['DIFF_HOURS'] > i) & (df['DIFF_HOURS'] <= (i+6))]['DIFF_HOURS'].apply(lambda x: i)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems work fine. But I get warnings: "See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  isetter(ilocs[0], value)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1743: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: Hard to say which part caused this exactly cause this oneliner is very messy. In general you don't have to worry about that, if you get the result you want - it just warns you of a possibility you might not really be assigning anything. If you're sure you do - you can supress the warning.
Of course it would be better to cleanup the filtering, for example using _pd.DataFrame.query()_ or splitting this into more lines (extracting indices of interest, assigning)
Also you don't really seem to need _apply_ at all here, since it's just replacing values.

Comment: If you'd like, provide a sample df, and I can try to clean this a bit

Comment: Finally my basic solution which works fine and fast:

every_hours = 6
max_periode = 72

for i in range(0, max_periode, every_hours):
      df.loc[(df['DIFF_HOURS'] > i) & (df['DIFF_HOURS'] <= (i+6)), 'DIFF_HOURS'] = i But i have always the same warning

Comment: Add sample dataframe please